# understanding canDeactivateFn syntax using Angular Documentation

Tags: angular, typescript

I found out that `canDeactivate()` guard in Angular is deprecated, but `canDeactivateFn` guard works perfectly fine. I am still a first year university student, so reading official documentation is a bit new for me. What I understood is that `canActivateFn` & `canDeactivateFn` are now functions and not classes. You directly use the component you want to use `canDeactivateFn` in the function definition, This is how I defined my `canDeactivateFn` function.

```js
/*
  I just want to automatically save data when a user leaves a component.
*/
export const leaveRoute: CanDeactivateFn<EnglishComponent> = (
  // the component I want to edit is called EnglishComponent
  component: EnglishComponent, 
  currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
  currentState: RouterStateSnapshot, 
  nextState: RouterStateSnapshot):
  Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree  => {
    // This 'hello' does not even execute. how do I make this logic execute when I try to leave the component
    console.log('hello')
    component.formValue = component.form.value
    component.form.setValue(component.formValue)
    return true
  }
```

My Routing looks like this.

```js
{
        path: 'en',
        component: EnglishComponent,
        canDeactivate: [(component: EnglishComponent) => true]
},
```

Now, my question is, How can I properly using the `canDeactivateFn` guard? What do I need to add and what do I need to remove? Preferably, I would like someone to quote from official Angular documentation to help me practice reading it and understanding it, but if you don't want to then that's okay.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Couple of answers for this, from what I can see. I'll preface this with: I have never used this function before.

Oh, also as a preface: I have no idea what you're attempting to do. It looks like you're attempting to set form data on the form you're navigating away from, which would be pointless because that form is about to be destroyed.

That said, I'm going to assume you know what you're doing and it's set up in some way that isn't represented by your given code.

So I'mma ignore your code.

Ok, options. Option the first, if it's reasonable: don't use navigation directly to deal with it.

If you're navigating away, presumably you are, in some fashion, destroying the component. You can therefore use `OnDestroy`:

```js
export class MyFormComponent implements OnDestroy {
    // ...

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // Do whatever saving you want in here before the component dies
    }
}
```

I'm assuming this form component is encapsulated by some parent and you want to give that form data to the parent (either via a service or an `@Output` emission?).

So yeah, before I start playing with something more complex like navigation, I'd do that. Especially if it involves saving things in some form (usually, the can deactivate things are used for "You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave?" kind of popups rather than any complex saving logic).

However, I think the core of your question is around how you can use your method in the router. Given your addition of your current level of usage, I assume you're just not quite familiar with anonymous methods and their usages, so here's a quick version of things:

Methods are just 'things', like numbers and strings. Therefore, they can be slapped in a variable and used at a later date, just like number and strings, etc.

```js
const someFn = () => true;
const addStuff = (a, b) => a + b;
```

Whenever I then call `someFn()` I get a `true` value out of it. That's all that's happening in the guard line: `canDeactivate: [(component: EnglishComponent) => true]`
You're just returning true all the time.

And `addStuff` becomes a little in-line addition method you can use `const x = addStuff(1, 2);`

You could put your code in there in-line, but that would be messy:

```js
canDeactivate: [(component: EnglishComponent) => {
    console.log('hello')
    component.formValue = component.form.value
    component.form.setValue(component.formValue)
    return true
}]
```

or you can move it out and save that method, and then use that, which is much cleaner:

```js
const canDeactivateEnglishComponent = (component: EnglishComponent) => {
    console.log('hello')
    component.formValue = component.form.value
    component.form.setValue(component.formValue)
    return true
};

...

canDeactivate: [(component: EnglishComponent) => canDeactivateEnglishComponent(component)]
```

And so the `canDeactivate` is calling your method inside it.
Technically, your method meets the relevant signature requirements, such that you can actually use it directly rather than having your little anon function call your function...

```js
canDeactivate: [canDeactivateEnglishComponent]
```

Probably. Don't have my IDE up to recreate it and confirm, but that variable IS a method of the relevant signature type, so it should be able to be use AS the method item itself without the anon method wrapping.

However, after all that, I'd say make use of your component itself and the `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook to do any kind of form value emitting when it starts to get destroyed rather than trying to put any complex logic into the navigation guard - unless it was particularly relevant to how you have your system hooked up.